# Display textarea value in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have posts. When I click edit it takes me to the edit screen and display current post values. However for some reason the input is displayed while textarea is not. I can't understand why.

Works perfectly, displays value.

```
<input class = "form-control" type="text" name = 'body' value = "{{ old('body', $post->body ?? null) }}" />
```

It doesn't display value for body.

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name = 'body'  rows="3" value = "{{ old('body', $post->body ?? null) }}" ></textarea>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

input is self closing tag that's why in input you can set value via `value=`
and in textarea there is closing tag that's why in textarea you can't set value via `value` attribute

```html
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name = 'body'  rows="3"> {{ old('body', $post->body) }}</textarea>
```

Comment: You don't have to use null coalescing operator. Laravel will handle that.

Answer (score 1):

**The textarea tag has no value**, but work fine with handlebars.it has placeholder attribute but here it not work like this https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-textarea-placeholder
So just give the value before close tag

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name = 'body'  rows="3" >{{ old('body', $post->body ?? null) }}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

****Display textarea value in Laravel**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Vendor Description</label>
            <textarea name="dec" class="form-control" rows="3" value="{{old('dec')}}"></textarea> {!! $errors->first('dec', '
            <p class="text-danger errorBag">:message</p>') !!}


            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="l_name" class="form-control 
                            " value="{{old('l_name')}}"> {!! $errors->first('l_name', '
            <p class="text-danger errorBag">:message</p>') !!}
        </div>
```